# Trying to connect to REST API with authorization header - PowerBI Desktop

Tags: authorization, jwt, powerbi

I am trying to connect to REST service from PowerBI Desktop.

Everything is running smoothly from PyCharm's REST client, however each time when I try to connect to the same source from PowerBI i got Authorisation error.

PyCharm REST Client request:

[image: Pycharm REST request]

And response:

[image: Pycharm REST response]

PowerBI:

[image: PowerBI connection]

[image: PowerBI error]

What do I do wrong? Any tips? All paths are the same (copy-paste from PyCharm, checked multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

In your PyCharm it says `Cache-Control`, but in Power BI it becomes `CacheControl`.

Comment: No, it does not have any impact - even when I remove this header PyCharm is able to connect, PowerBI - not.